# Remove the anchor tag if the user has changed an input

Tags: jquery

I'm tryng to do

```
$('input').change(function() {
   $('a').removeAttr('href');
});
```

And this works like you would think it would, except that it still leaves an empty a tag.  I'd like to unwrap the a tag all together.  I tried:

```
$('input').change(function() {
   $('a').unwrap();
});
```

But I think that removed the parent element, not the anchor tag itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('a').after($('a').text());
$('a').remove();
```

UPDATE:

if you actually need to do this for every a tag and not just a specific one (i don't see why you would, but just in case)...

```
$('a').each(function(){$(this).after($(this).text());});
$('a').remove();
```

Comment: Ah, thank you for the update.  The reason why I needed it for every anchor tag is because I don't want the user to enter something into a field and then navigate away from the page without pressing the submit button.